# add button to contentPane which uses java graphics

Tags: java, graphics, jframe

I'm having trouble adding a button to this JFrame, it's having a conflict with the java graphics thing that i'm using. The stuff that's in comments is what i've tried so far, that doesn't worked.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class JFramePaint1 {
//Button draw;
public static JButton  b = new JButton("button");

   public static void main(String[] a) {

  JFrame f = new JFrame();

      f.setTitle("Drawing Graphics in Frames");
     f.setSize(800, 650);
  f.setLocation(200,50);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  //f.add(b);

  f.setContentPane( new ContentComponent());
  //f.getContentPane.add(b);

        f.setVisible(true);
   }
   static class ContentComponent extends JComponent {
     public int activa = 1;
 // add(b);
  //this.add(b);
     public void paint(Graphics g) {


   g.setColor (Color.RED);
   g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 650);
   if( activa == 1){

   g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   g.drawRect(40, 20, 150, 80);
   int x = 40;
   int y= 20;
   for(int i = 0; i< 4; i++){

   g.drawRect(x+10, y+10, 150, 80);
   x = x+10;
   y = y+10;
   }

   }

   // g.fillRect(20, 10, 100, 60);
  // g.drawRect(40, 20, 150, 80);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `ContentComponent` subclass `JPanel` instead of `JComponent` and then add the button to the panel directly or via `f.getContentPane().add(b)`.

A JPanel is designed to have subcomponents; it is a container.

Answer (score 2):

It really doesn't matter whether you use a JComponent or a JPanel, both are containers.

The difference is that by default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout, but a JComponent does not use any layout manager, so if you want to use a JCompnent you need to set the layout manager.

Custom painting should be done by overriding the paintComponent() method. You should also invoke super.paintComponent(...). Another difference between the two is that a JPanel will paint your background automatically but a JComponent won't.

Also, be consistent with the formatting of your code. Use spaces or tabs consistently. The posted code is terrible to read because of the formatting.